# adding 'at' to a date in PHP

Tags: php, date, format

I want to create a date format like "May 17 at 23:02", which according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should be like this:

```
echo date("M d \a\t H:i",time());
```

but this echoes:

```
May 17 a 23:02
```

the t is missing and I don't know why.

Comment: why does this question get a downvote? It's unexpected behaviour, I don't see why this question could not be of help to someone struggling with the same problem

Comment: I agree, it's a duplicate of that question. I couldn't find that answer before. Shall I remove this post here?

Answer (score -1):

For some reason someone here might be able to explain adding 'at' requires the 't' to be escaped twice:

```
echo date("M d \a\\t H:i")
```

will echo the desired output

Comment: If you use double quotes `"` for your string, the backslash is also interpreted literally, resulting in `\t`, which is the escape sequence for the horizontal tab character. Using single quotes `'` or double escaping as you did prevents this and actually results in a `t`.

Comment: `t` is used for the "*[number] of days in the given month*", `\t` is a tab-space, `\\t` escapes the backslash which escapes the `t`.